# Bulk insert with EF ExecuteStoreCommand not working, what is wrong?

Tags: entity-framework, bulkinsert

I am using SQL 2008 and EF
I have following stored proc for bulk insert

```
CREATE Type [dbo].[xxx] as Table (
[ErrorCode] [nvarchar](10),
[ErrorMessage] [nvarchar](300),
[FieldName] [nvarchar](50),
[FieldLable] [nvarchar](300),
)
CREATE procedure dbo.InsertAll(@Records xxx READONLY)
as
begin

insert into dbo.MyTable
    select * from @Records;
end;
go
```

I am passing a Datatable as parameter (Type=structured) that has multiple records
This proc works when called using SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, but does not do anything when called using contextObject.ExecuteStoreCommand. The return value = affected rows is always 0

Whats wrong? are such procedures not supported with EF? I am not even getting any exception :(

Update: After running SQL trace just realized the difference in the SQL statements being generated

When using contextObject.ExecuteStoreCommand

```
declare @p3 dbo.xxx
insert into @p3 values(N'M',N'ErrorMsg - 0',NULL,NULL)
insert into @p3 values(N'M',N'ErrorMsg - 1',NULL,NULL)
insert into @p3 values(N'M',N'ErrorMsg - 2',NULL,NULL)
exec sp_executesql N'InsertAll',N'@Records [xxx]
READONLY',@Records=@p3
```

When using SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

```
declare @p1 dbo.xxx
insert into @p1 values(N'M',N'ErrorMsg - 0',NULL,NULL)
insert into @p1 values(N'M',N'ErrorMsg - 1',NULL,NULL)
insert into @p1 values(N'M',N'ErrorMsg - 2',NULL,NULL)
exec InsertAll @Records=@p1
```

How can I get contextObject.ExecuteStoreCommand to execute the same SQL stmt like SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I have found it necessary to provide extension methods when the Entity Framework simply will not work for what I want it to do.  The good part is adding an extension to the Context object will usually keep you from having to dig into the web.config or app.config for a connection string.  Then parameters and return values can be generic.  I have personally seen quite a few eloquent solutions using this strategy.